# Use \Updownright between two vertical expressions

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath, arrows

I have a long equation

```
\ldots - m \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow \ldots \neq m
```

where `\ldots` is a long expression.

Instead of having this on one line, can I instead format it to obtain

```
\ldots - m \neq 0
\Updownright
\ldots \neq 0
```

Comment: Mathtools have an `\ArrowBetweenLines` that you might want to check out

Comment: Do you mean `\Updownarrow`?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry

Comment: \ArrowBetweenLines seems to add either left or right alignment instead of centering it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach depends on which display math environment you're using. If you want all of your equations to be **centered**, then it's best to use the `gather` or `gather*` environments (`gather` numbers each equation, and `gather*` doesn't). In this case, `\ArrowBetweenLines` produces a centered arrow.

```
% Assumes mathtools package is loaded
\begin{gather*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 0\\
\ArrowBetweenLines
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 0
\end{gather*}
```

If you want your equations to be **aligned** vertically along some common line (usually `=` or an inequality sign), then you're using `align` or `align*` (again, the starred version is unnumbered). In this case, `\ArrowBetweenLines` should also be aligned, but it doesn't do this, so we'll make our own.

```
% Again, requires mathtools
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 &= 0\\[-1\jot]
&\phantom{=}\mathclap{\Updownarrow}\\[-1\jot]
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 &= 0
\end{align*}
```

This produces an arrow aligned with the `=` signs. If you're going to do this a lot, it might also help to define a macro.

Here's what these two code samples look like:

[image]

Comment: It looks a lot better if you use alignat and give the first alignment column to the Updownarrow

Comment: @daleif: as in, to the left of the equations? That does sound nicer.

Comment: Yes that is the intended use. The starred version if for when (again with alignat) you want it on the right

Comment: @daleif: Oh, that makes sense. Well, I guess I learned something new today...

Comment: It is mentioned in the manual ;-)

Comment: @daleif: in retrospect, the reason I tried this is that the OP said that `\ArrowBetweenLines` in normal use wasn't what they're looking for, I think?